# Deploying a Rails application on apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, apache2, config

Ive built a small application which interacts with mysql at the backend.When I run on the mongrel server its wrking fine.
I want to run this application on apache server.
The application is a rails application
OS is opensolaris
I tried to modify the httpd.conf in apache and added the follwing lines to it.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home/gems/passenger-2.2.15/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home/gems/passenger-2.2.15
   PassengerRuby /usr/ruby/1.8/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName sampleapp.com
      DocumentRoot /export/home/gaurav/test/sample_app/public
    <Directory /export/home/gaurav/test/sample_app>
      AllowOverride ALL
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`
```

But im getting a database error. I check the log file for error its showing error code 500

Comment: have you configure your production database ?

Comment: Can we have your log please ?

Comment: The same application is wrking with mogrel.So i guess the production database must be configured.but still i checked the database.yml file everything is fine there.

Comment: Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Unknown database 'sample_prod'
    /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:619:in `real_connect'
    /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:619:in `connect'
    /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
    /var/ruby/1.8/gem_home/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/conne...................................

Comment: I wanted to ask that how can the rails applicationo run on mogrel then and not in apache when even the database 'sample_prod' was not there I dont even need that.But when i remove it from the database.yml file its gives some error of production d/b missing

Comment: @gaurav: next time when adding data like logs, try updating your question instead of leaving large chunks of code in comments

Comment: I think @shingara has it right first time. I believe that Mongrel is running by default in development mode whereas Passenger is running in production more. Either set `RackEnv` to development or set up your production database

Answer (score 0):

You need define a production database in your db/database.yml file and create this database with all migration

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

Or if you really don't want use production environment, you can change it on your passenger configuration

Comment: Hi shingara..The RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create command worked..but when im running the next command its giving.(in /usr/home/gaurav/demo/sample_app)
rake aborted!
Cipher is not a module

Comment: it's another problem. Cipher is in our Gem I suppose or your code.